# How to override include setting of tsconfig without creating tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript

This is our `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": [
      "es2021",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2018"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

The undesired side effect of this config is that the output is going to include both `src` and `tests`, i.e.

```bash
$ tree dist -L 1
dist
├── src
└── tests

2 directories, 0 files
```

It appears that in order to produce a build that only includes `src`, I need to create a new `tsconfig.json` file, e.g. `tsconfig.build.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

which is a bit of a nuisance when you have a monorepo with hundreds of packages.

Is there a way to override `include` setting when using `tsc` CLI program?

Comment: No, but you can compile without a config file using only [CLI arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).